# How to query pyarrow table stuct field

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a table, let's say 2 columns A (list), B (list) and 2 rows:

```
A: ["X", "Y"], ["Y", "Z"]
B: [1, 3], [5, 6]
```

I'd like to achieve something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE A.Y = 5` and it'd return a single (second) row. How do I achieve this using `pyarrow.compute`?

I was looking into `pc.index_in` and `pc.equals`, but they don't handle lists. Also I tried `C = StructArray.from_arrays([A, B])`, but again, I don't know how to write `SELECT * FROM table WHERE C.Y = 5`.

Also I didn't find a way, to "normalize"/"unstack" the data, so by using `Y` the table would become:

```
A: ["X"], ["Z"]
B: [1], [6]
Y: 3, 5
```

It might be a wrong design, but basically I'm looking for two functions like
`Give me the vector of indexes of 'Y' in column A.` - this would return [1,0] in the example above
And then `Give me the values from column B at index {the vector from the previous result, so [1,0]}` which would result in [3,5].

Answer (score 2):

For list arrays in pyarrow you can use `list_flatten` and `list_flatten_indices` to explode the table:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.Series([["X", "Y"], ["Y", "Z"]], name="A"),
        pd.Series([[1, 3], [5, 6]], name="B"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)


flat_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [
        pc.list_flatten(table["A"]),
        pc.list_flatten(table["B"]),
        pc.list_parent_indices(table["A"]),
    ],
    names=["A", "B", "index"],
)
```

| A | B | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 0 |
| Y | 3 | 0 |
| Y | 5 | 1 |
| Z | 6 | 1 |

But at the moment there isn't a good API for pivotting the table back as you want it. You can try to implement it your self but it's vey ad hoc.

```py
sub_tables = []
keys = sorted(pc.unique(flat_table["A"]).to_pylist())
for key in keys:
    sub_table = pc.filter(flat_table, pc.equal(flat_table["A"], key))
    sub_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
        [
            sub_table["index"],
            sub_table["B"],
        ],
        names=["index", key],
    )
    sub_tables.append(sub_table)

results = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [pa.array(range(len(table)), pa.int64())], names=["index"]
)
for sub_table, key in zip(sub_tables, keys):
    results = results.join(sub_table, keys="index")

results = results.select(keys)
```

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nan | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | nan |