# Using pyarrow read_json() to parse a list of structs into a StructArray

Tags: python, json, pyarrow

I can successfully use `pyarrow` `read_json` to read some JSON financial trading data into a table. The JSON contains two lists of structs, `asks` and `bids`.

```
schema = pa.schema([('time', pa.timestamp(unit='ns', tz='UTC'))])

parse_options = pj.ParseOptions(explicit_schema=schema)

table = pj.read_json(file, parse_options=parse_options)
```

```
table
```

```
pyarrow.Table
time: timestamp[ns, tz=UTC]
instrument: string
asks: list<item: struct<price: string, liquidity: int64>>
  child 0, item: struct<price: string, liquidity: int64>
      child 0, price: string
      child 1, liquidity: int64
bids: list<item: struct<price: string, liquidity: int64>>
  child 0, item: struct<price: string, liquidity: int64>
      child 0, price: string
      child 1, liquidity: int64
ask_prices: list<item: struct<price: string, liquidity: int64>>
  child 0, item: struct<price: string, liquidity: int64>
      child 0, price: string
      child 1, liquidity: int64
```

If I then look at the first row `asks` or `bids` fields, they are ListArray(s). I would like to read this data into StructArray(s) so that I can use the `field()` method.

I'm pretty sure I need to specify the StructArray in the schema, but I'm struggling to make this work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

A sample line of JSON is...

```
{"type": "PRICE", "time": "2022-01-04T15:55:12.710818633Z", "bids": [{"price": "1.13134", "liquidity": 1000000}, {"price": "1.13133", "liquidity": 2000000}, {"price": "1.13132", "liquidity": 2000000}, {"price": "1.13130", "liquidity": 5000000}], "asks": [{"price": "1.13145", "liquidity": 1000000}, {"price": "1.13147", "liquidity": 2000000}, {"price": "1.13148", "liquidity": 2000000}, {"price": "1.13149", "liquidity": 5000000}], "closeoutBid": "1.13130", "closeoutAsk": "1.13149", "status": "tradeable", "tradeable": true, "instrument": "EUR_USD"}
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your json data to your question?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Sample JSON added to question.

Comment: The 'asks' and 'bids' fields appear sorted, but they are not. Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is convert the 'price' of each ask/bid to a float, and then extract the lowest ask price and the highest bid price.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the JSON to a structure of {time: ..., instrument: ..., ask: ..., bid: ...}. I can filter out the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I then look at the first row asks or bids fields, they are ListArray(s). I would like to read this data into StructArray(s) so that I can use the field() method.

The fields bids and asks are list of struct, there's nothing you can do about it when parsing the data.

Ultimately if you want to extract these fields, the first thing you need to do it "explode" them. There is an API for this in [pyarrow.compute](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html) but it's not easy to use. You can also refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72878590/how-to-query-pyarrow-table-stuct-field/72880717#72880717). Then you groupby and get the min/max, and put it back together with a join.

```py
import pyarrow.compute as pc

bids_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [
        pc.take(table['time'], pc.list_parent_indices(table['bids'])),
        pc.list_flatten(table['bids']),
    ],
    names=['time', 'bid']
).flatten()

best_bid = pa.TableGroupBy(bids_table, ['time']).aggregate([('bid.price', 'max')])
```

| time | bid.price_max |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 15:55:12.710818633+00:00 | 1.13134 |

```py
asks_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [
        pc.take(table['time'], pc.list_parent_indices(table['asks'])),
        pc.list_flatten(table['asks']),
    ],
    names=['time', 'ask']
).flatten()

best_ask = pa.TableGroupBy(asks_table, ['time']).aggregate([('ask.price', 'min')])
```

| time | ask.price_min |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 15:55:12.710818633+00:00 | 1.13145 |

```py
both = best_bid.join(best_ask, keys=['time'])
```

| time | bid.price_max | ask.price_min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 15:55:12.710818633+00:00 | 1.13134 | 1.13145 |

PS: you might be better serve by polars to do this

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply, I really appreciate the time you have put into answering my question. It is all quite complicated, and as you suggest there may be more succinct alternatives. I have actually found a quick method using a Dask Bag and a simple list comprehension, which works well and is short and easy to reason about. jq has potential too. I was hoping to do all of my preprocessing in a single pyarrow script, but that is proving to be too complicated. I will look into Polars. Thank you.